# Matlab - Rotate 3D subplots in unison

Tags: matlab, events, plot

I want to be able to rotate these 3 subplots (or an indefinite number of them) in unison. In clearer terms, while I rotate any one of the subplots, the other subplots view([az el]) should track the subplot I am interacting with.

How would I go about accomplishing this?

[image]

Sample code:

```
[t p]=meshgrid(deg2rad(0:2:180),deg2rad(-180:2:180));

x=sin(t).*cos(p);
y=sin(t).*sin(p);
z=cos(t);

F1=cos(t+pi/6).^2;
F2=cos(t+2*pi/6).^2;
F3=cos(t+3*pi/6).^2;

figure;
subplot(1,3,1)
surf(x,y,z,F1,'EdgeColor','none')
axis vis3d
subplot(1,3,2)
surf(x,y,z,F2,'EdgeColor','none')
axis vis3d
subplot(1,3,3)
surf(x,y,z,F3,'EdgeColor','none')
axis vis3d
```

Comment: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkprop.html

Comment: @AnderBiguri thanks. I'll have a followup question. How might I have discovered this on my own? Did you know where to look, or used better keywords perhaps?

Comment: There is a similar question on MATLAB Answers website - https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/251728-how-to-rotate-subplots-at-the-same-time

Comment: r.e. search terms, Google with the `site:` specifier is usually a good way to search within documentation sites or stackoverflow, e.g. searching `matlab link 3d plot rotation site:stackoverflow.com` gave the question I've linked as a duplicate (`subplot` instead of `link` works for me too), which contains an answer illustrating how to use `linkprop()`.

Comment: @berala in this case, I just happened to have had the same issue in the past. This is a good non-trivial question.